# deduce argument type from its iterator

Tags: c++, templates, typename

I'm trying to implement the Haskell function `foldr` in C++:

```
template <typename F, typename ForwardIter, typename B>
B foldr(F f, B z0, ForwardIter begin, ForwardIter end)
{
    if (begin == end) {
        return z0;
    } else {
        auto lval = *begin;
        return f(lval, foldr(f, z0, ++begin, end));
    }
}
```

My question is. Can I deduce the type `F` to `std::function` using info from `ForwardIter`?
Imaginary type: F = `std::function<B(typename ForwardIter::value, B)>`

Considering the Haskell signature `(a->b->b)->b->[a]->b` that indicates the relationship between arguments, I'm wondering if there is one way to specify this kind of relationship in C++. So that when I incidentally passing a wrong functor to 1st argument, the compiler would tell me that she need a functor with exact signature.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: What are you *specifically* looking for? Do you want to have a template argument list that is *only* the iterator type, and *nothing else* ?

Comment: Considering the Haskell signature `(a->b->b)->b->[a]->b` that indicates the relationship between arguments, I'm wondering if there is one way to specify this kind of relationship in C++. So that when I incidentally passing a wrong functor to 1st argument, the compiler would tell me that she need a functor with exact signature. @Nawaz      @WhozCraig

Comment: @RealYang: `enable_if` and `is_callable` are you friends. The latter is rather easy to write with `std::declval` and expression-SFINAE. An example implementation can be found [here](http://ideone.com/5uMxuR).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Considering the Haskell signature `(a->b->b)->b->[a]->b` that indicates the relationship between arguments, I'm wondering if there is one way to specify this kind of relationship in C++.

Yes, there is. You are misguided in thinking that one does that with `std::function`, though. `std::function` is *a container for callables with a known signature*. Why would one wrap stuff in a container just for passing it as an argument?

You can simply use a trailing return type, for example:

```
template<typename F, 
         typename ForwardIter, 
         typename B,
         typename ValueType = typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIter>::value_type>
auto foldr(F f, B z0, ForwardIter begin, ForwardIter end)
-> decltype(std::declval<F&>()(std::declval<ValueType&>(), std::declval<B&>())) { ...
```

You can also define a trait for your requirements (i.e. `F` is callable with an argument of the `value_type` of the iterator and another of type`B`, and returning `B`), and use that trait to reject other callables.

```
template<typename F, 
         typename ForwardIter, 
         typename B>
B foldr(F f, B z0, ForwardIter begin, ForwardIter end)
{
    using ValueType = typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIter>::value_type;
    static_assert(is_callable<F&, B(ValueType&, B&)>(), "F must be callable with signature B(B, B)");
    ...
```

This will cause an error if the object is not callable with the right signature. If you only want the overload to be excluded from overload resolution you can use SFINAE with `enable_if`

```
template<typename F, 
         typename ForwardIter, 
         typename B,
         typename ValueType = typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIter>::value_type,
         typename std::enable_if<is_callable<F&, B(ValueType&,B&)>::value, int>::type = 0>
B foldr(F f, B z0, ForwardIter begin, ForwardIter end) { ...
```

Or you can use that trait for tag dispatching. Or whatever. The important bit is that this is not what `std::function` was made for (and it's not just a problem of runtime overhead; it also makes certain code fail to compile when it would work just fine without the `std::function` obsession).

---

All that said, if I was writing this function, I would start more or less like this (note all the reference semantics and forwarding going on):

```
template<typename F, 
         typename It, 
         typename B,
         typename Reference = typename std::iterator_traits<It>::reference,
         typename std::enable_if<is_callable<F&, B(Reference&&,B)>::value, int>::type = 0>
B foldr(F&& f, B&& z0, It first, It last)
{
    if (first == end) {
        return std::forward<B>(z0);
    } else {
        auto&& r = *first; // must do here to avoid order of evaluation woes
        // don't forward f because we cannot "destroy" it twice, i.e. no moving!
        return f(std::forward<decltype(r)>(r), foldr(f, std::forward<B>(z0), ++first, end));
    }
}
```

Comment: FWIW, I use this https://github.com/rmartinho/wheels/blob/stable/include/wheels/fun for my "callability" tests.

Comment: I wish my clang would take the last declaration, but alas, it pukes on the self-referencing `typename Result = typename std::result_of<F&(Reference&&, Result)>::type>`

Answer (score 2):

Use the `decltype` keyword.  The use of `auto` in your code suggests you are using C++11.  At the top of your function:

```
typedef decltype(*begin) ForwardIterValue;          // type of result of applying dereference operator
typedef std::function< B(ForwardIterValue, B) > F;  // desired function object
```

As the [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decltype) says,

> Its primary intended use is in generic programming, where it is often
>   difficult, or even impossible, to express types that depend on
>   template parameters

Depending on how you construct the function object, using `auto` for that as well might be possible.

Comment: Would it be any possible that I declare this function using `std::function<???>` as the 1st argument?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it would be possible. The advantage is that if you call `foldr` repeatedly with many different functions, but the same types for `ForwardIterator` and `B`, you will only get one version of the generated code, and thus (potentially) a smaller executable.

However, my instinct says *"don't do it"*. Precisely because of the generic properties of `std::function`, the compiler has little chance of inlining your call to `f()`; in turn, it may have difficulty unwinding the recursive call to `foldr`. On the other hand, if you allow it to synthesize a specialized `foldr` for each function, you've got a much better chance of getting a highly optimised implementation. This is particularly true if `f` is something simple, like `std::plus` or something similar.

For example, trying the following with Clang 3.1 at -03:

```
std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4};
std::cout << foldr(std::plus{}, 5, v.begin(), v.end()) << std::endl;
```

leads to the call to `foldr` being completely eliminated. A version of the same code using `std::function` has much more overhead.

Of course, instinct and gut feeling are particularly terrible ways of deciding whether or not to do something, and that goes double when C++ templates get involved. I would suggest trying both approaches and seeing which turns out better.

Comment: But how could I declare this function using `std::function` as the 1st argument's type instead of template type `F`? Would it be possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIter>::value_type` if either

- the iterator has a member `typedef ... value_type;`, *or*
- an appropriate specialisation of `iterator_traits` exists (e.g. for pointers).